# How can I check if the single chars are allowed?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-match, pcre

I have an array with 5 single chars. They shall be checked with this regex:

```
$regex = "/[a-zA-Z0-9]/";
```

How can I check if the single chars are allowed?

Comment: To validate single characters, your expression should be `/^[A-Za-z0-9]$/` with `^$` anchors. Otherwise, multichar expressions would match

Comment: We can only give you an answer as good as the question, i.e. `How can I check if the single chars are allowed?` in what sense do you mean? That is a vague question.

Comment: To be frank, your English needs some polishing. No hard feelings from me, but the less text you write, the more assumptions people have to make about what you really meant. Or to turn it around: the more detailed your question is, the less impact your knowledge of English will have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [preg_grep](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) that accepts an array as well:

```
$matchedArray = preg_grep("/[a-zA-Z0-9]/", $array);
```

As per the doc: [preg_grep](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) returns the array consisting of the elements of the input array that match the given pattern.

Then you can do:

```
if ($array === $matchedArray)
    echo "matched\n";
```

Comment: can it return something like true or false so I can know if it is legal or not?

Answer (score 1):

Why not check them as a string?

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+$/i',implode('',$yourCharArray)))
{
    echo 'all chars are ok';
}
```

Oh, and in case you were wondering `/[a-z]/i` is the same as `/[a-zA-Z]/`, `i` is the case-insensitive flag.

If you still want/need to check each element individually, as your comment leads me to believe:

```
foreach($yourChars as $char)
{
    if (!preg_match('/[a-z0-9]/i',$char))
    {
        echo 'Error: '.$char.' is not allowed';
    }
}
```

But in this case, I'd advise *not* to use a regex. just:

```
if (!ctype_alnum($char))
```

Will do, it's faster and does exactly what you need it to do. [see the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php)
And again, implode the array and checking the length of the resulting string is still a lot faster:

```
$check = implode('',$charArr);
if (strlen($check) > 5 || !ctype_alnum($check))
{//more than 5 chars, other chars than a-z/0-9
    echo 'invalid input';
}
//if > 5 should be allowed, but the array elements should be single chars:
if (strlen($check) > count($charArr) || !ctype_alnum($check))
```

Comment: If you want to go there, `/[a-z\d]/i` would be even shorter... :)

Comment: The only problem with the single string is that you will lose context. Imagine a person puts in 4 elements but 2 characters for the first one. This no longer probably validates to the rest of his programming but does for this function, if this were used to validate data it could be a valid security hole.

Comment: @Sammaye: Just addressed that in my last update `strlen($string) > count($array)` :) @dualed: true... I but this isn't supposed to be a crash course in regex's :)

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over the array and check one by one if they match this pattern?

Comment: Hum, sounds logic... But I also know that, the question is HOW?

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp does not have the quantity defined

You can use {} to do that. The follow regex accepts 1 to 5 chars, of the kind specified by the []

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}`

Or you can use '+' for "one or more", or without the comma to a fixed number of chars.

Comment: You don't need to define a quantity for a single character only for multiple char patterns, since it is 1 char in each array this would probably be better in a loop using the `^$` to denote that only one character should exist within that string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you need to check input to contain **just** pattern, you need to add anchors:

```
^pattern$
```

where `^` is beginning of string/line and `$` is its end.

Regarding pattern, use on of these >>

Single character:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

None or one character:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]?
```

One or more character(s):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

None or more character(s):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

Exact number of characters (n):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{n}
```

Number of characters in range (n,m):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{n,m}
```

n or more characters:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9](n,}
```

Not more than n characters:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,n}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but you could just loop the array?

```
$myArray = ('0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'L');
$validArray = true;
foreach ($myArray as $value) {
    if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]/", $value) == 0)
            $validArray = false;
}
```

This would validate the entire array and you could wrap it into a function. But like I said, I'm not sure exactly what you need.

As a side note you could create a function from this:

```
function validateArray($arr) {
    $validArray = true;
    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]/", $value) == 0)
                $validArray = false;
    }
    return $validArray;
}

$myArray = ('0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'L');
$myArrayValid = validateArray($myArray);
```

Comment: ok, so preg_match returns a bool which determines if the string matches with the pattern

Comment: Sorry. I'm a .NET developer so I should have seen it before posting. preg_match returns 1 if match was found or 0 if not found.

Already edited my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: Using `!` was better since preg_match can also return false, since false or `0` are incorrect values fore the function and should cause it to raise an error `!` was a good choice to use since it encompasses both values.

Comment: I´m a .NET developer, too. And i´m not good in php, that´s why I have to ask such silly questions...